# when Updating items in DynamoDB giving error Invalid UpdateExpression using NodeJS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

This is my handler function.

```
const updateOrder = (request) => {
    const id = request.pathParams.id;
    const orderObject = request.body;
    if(!id || !orderObject)
        throw new Error ('Please provide required id and object in order to update the order')


        const params = {
            TableName: "pizza-order",
            Key: {
                "orderId": id
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET  #n = :n, #a = :a ",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#n": "pizza",
                "#a": "address"
            },
            ConditionExpression: '' ,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
                ":n": orderObject.pizza,
                ":a": orderObject.address,
            },
            
        };

        return docClient.update(params).promise()

}
```

And the order Object is:

```
{
    "pizza":"THe outstanding pizza",
    "Address": "feni"
}
```

And it returns error like this. I don't know why it is happening. Very new to serverless development. anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very silly mistake. First in the order Object there is a typo:

```
{
    "pizza":"THe outstanding pizza",
    "address": "feni" //previously it was Address: "feni
}
```

And the second reason is ConditionExpression Can not be empty.

```
const updateOrder = (request) => {
    const id = request.pathParams.id;
    const orderObject = request.body;
    if(!id || !orderObject)
        throw new Error ('Please provide required id and object in order to update the order')

        const params = {
            TableName: "pizza-order",
            Key: {
                "orderId": id
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET  #n = :n, #a = :a ",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#n": "pizza",
                "#a": "address"
            },
            ConditionExpression: '' , // this can not be empty
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":n": orderObject.pizza,
                ":a": orderObject.address,
            },
            
        };

        return docClient.update(params).promise()

}
```